# Encode % to pass in URL javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to pass the below string to a GET API method call. However since the string has a `%`in it, it becomes a bad url. How do I achieve this?

I have a `query` json

```
var world = JSON.stringify(query);

console.log(world);
```

**Output:**

> { "world" : "keyvalue" : { "data" : {"key" : "hundred","value" : "100%"} } }

I then pass this to the API as below

```
var uri = '../api/hello_world/test/' + world;
```

**API call:**

```
 server.route ({
    path: '/api/hello_world/test/{text*}',
    method: 'GET',
    handler: async function (req, reply) {
    console.log(req)
    ...
```

The request is not getting sent to the API as the url becomes invalid with `%%22` - `%22` for `"`

I tried encoding with `encodeURI(world)` and the url now has `%25%22`. The request seems to be invalid here as well.

Not sure how to resolve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If it is not the whole URI that is being encoded, then use *encodeURIComponent*

Comment: That doesn't work too!

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere else. What is the error you get? How do you know it "doesn't work"? What framework are you using?